# Apache LocationMatch named regular expression strange behavior

Tags: apache, openid, mod-auth-openidc

I'm trying to create dynamic apache config for lots of directories with OpenID auth, but I never got it to work, I think that there's something wrong with named regexp, but I don't know.

Here's my virtualhost config:

```
AliasMatch ^/backup/(.*)$ /user_server_backups/$1
    <LocationMatch "^/backup/(?<sitename>[^/]+)">
            Require claim "roles:%{env:MATCH_SITENAME}"
            AuthType openid-connect
    </LocationMatch>
```

Whenever I try to access  I got 401
I tried also using numbered regexp but as described in docs numbered regexps are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use at least version 2.4.2.1 of `mod_auth_openidc`, see: https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/pull/469